# Scrolling has suddenly stopped working in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have tried turning all plugins off, deleting all custom CSS, deleting new entries, etc.  Suddenly, scrolling stopped working on all single posts in my Website... My client is pissed, and I can;t figure out where the problem is.  The URL to see this not working is http://urm.case42.com/market-report-august-29-2014/

Comment: Look at the errors in console... There are like 5. Why don't you fix them?

Comment: Please DO NOT link to live sites.

Comment: Sorry - I will not link to a live site again - I'm aware of all the errors - removing the plugins eliminated most of them, with no resulting change.  I do appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: I'd love to just delete this stupid question. I'm sorry for any time I have wasted. It was answered nicely, but I didn't realize I had posted out of the rules...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure *why* it is happening, but you can fix it with this:

```
html {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

As others have pointed out, there are a ton of console errors. I would imagine that a rogue javascript plugin is causing this.

Answer (score 4):

on basic.css  you are define overflow:hidden at line 3 remove this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The page is riddled with errors.

[image]

I'd start by checking out line `836`, where it looks like your google font import has a markup error.

Comment: Thanks - The errors mostly go away when all plugins are disabled, with no functional change - I will be going back to fix errors later, but I do appreciate the help.